# Compiling foundation sass files with grunt-sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I have installed foundation 5 with bower. by `compass watch` there is no problem to compile foundation files but when i want to use grunt-sass plugin, i see this error:

```
Running "sass:development" (sass) task
Warning: C:\wamp\www\nik\myapp/scss/app.scss:2: error: file to import not found or unreadable: "foundation"
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Line 2 of app.scss is `@import "foundation"`.
And grunt-sass in my Gruntfile.js:

```
sass: {
      development: {
          options: {
              outputStyle: 'nested'
          },
          files: {
            '.css/development/style.css': ['scss/app.scss', 'scss/style.scss']
          }
      },
      production: {
          options: {
              outputStyle: 'compressed'
          },
          files: {
            '.css/development/style.css': ['scss/app.scss', 'scss/style.scss']
          }
      }
```

I also tested [this solution](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/776-foundation-5-sass-installation-wont-compile-on-windows-or-mac) but it had no affection.

Comment: Problem solved. When we use grunt to compile foundation scss files, we should use --libsass for installing foundation. `foundation new project_name --libsass`

Comment: Can you add any more detail (maybe as an answer to the question as well?)

Comment: @streetlight answer added.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding **`--libsass`** for installing foundation in command line, will cause installing foundation that is **compatible with grunt**:

```
foundation new A_PROJECT_NAME --libsass
```

Subsequently in grunt (after installing `grunt-sass`) :

```
sass: {
  development: {
      options: {
          outputStyle: 'nested', 
          // Adding foundation source files, so we can @import them.
          includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
      },
      files: {
        'css/style.css': ['path/to/styles/app.scss']
      }
  }
}
```

*Hint: you can import your own style.scss in app.scss last line.*